# Is there a way to set the background of an animation without affecting the lighting

Tags: cycles-render-engine, color

I have am trying to render my animation, a Rubiks cube scrambling it's self. I set the background to transparent but when I put it in my video editing software, it is black. If I were to use a chroma key of black, it would take out the base of the rubiks cube. When I change the background to aqua because the is no aqua anywhere on my rubiks cube, it affects the lighting. My rubiks cube has an aqua tint to it. Is there any way to get rid of that?

This is when I rendered the photo with the aqua background.
[image]

For this photo, I turned the background back to the grayish color and rendered it with a transparent background.
[image]

Comment: 1) render transparent background and then composite in the aqua with an alpha over node to a video file. or:
2) render transparent to images with alpha (.png/exr) and then import those images into your video editor and add a background there.

Comment: You may need to enable use alpha or alpha over in your video editor.

Comment: Please don't mark the question as **resolved** in the title. Unless the question has an accepted answer the system will mark the quesion as unanswered , so Please write a proper answer so that others facing the same issue will know what to do. Additionally read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer